# Mapstruct using varags not working

Tags: variadic-functions, mapstruct

I am trying to build a mapper using mapstruct. I have a mapping method that gets String and String Varags properties. I want to use the varags in AfterMapping annotation with some logic.
When I run mvn build I'm getting exception related to the varags (when removing it build pass successfully).
is there a way to use varags in mapstruct?

Here is the piece of code:

```
@Mappings({
    @Mapping(source = "code", target = "code")
})
MyResponse mapInformationToErrorData(String code, String... parameters);
```

Build is failing with below exception.

> ErrorMapper.java:[20,8] Internal error in the mapping processor: java.lang.NullPointerException      at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.util.workarounds.SpecificCompilerWorkarounds.replaceTypeElementIfNecessary(SpecificCompilerWorkarounds.java:112)        at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.util.Executables.getAllEnclosedAccessors(Executables.java:208)     at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.model.common.Type.getAllAccessors(Type.java:534)        at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.model.common.Type.getPropertyReadAccessors(Type.java:397)          at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.model.BeanMappingMethod$Builder.applyPropertyNameBasedMapping(BeanMappingMethod.java:529)       at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.model.BeanMappingMethod$Builder.build(BeanMappingMethod.java:145)          at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.MapperCreationProcessor.getMappingMethods(MapperCreationProcessor.java:373)   at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.MapperCreationProcessor.getMapper(MapperCreationProcessor.java:152)      at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.MapperCreationProcessor.process(MapperCreationProcessor.java:123)     at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.MapperCreationProcessor.process(MapperCreationProcessor.java:80)         at org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor.process(MappingProcessor.java:280)         at org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor.processMapperTypeElement(MappingProcessor.java:260)     at org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor.processMapperElements(MappingProcessor.java:226)   at org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor.process(MappingProcessor.java:162)         at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:794)      at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:705)   at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1800(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)         at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1035)    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1176)      at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:856)      at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)         at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:129)         at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:138)        at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:125)          at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile(JavacCompiler.java:171)      at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:886)      at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:129)         at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)          at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)      at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)          at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)

Comment: Looks like this is not possible. Use a string array/map instead. Or describe what is your high level goal so someone can suggest a better workaround.

Comment: If you want to use the varargs in `@AfterMapping` you will probably need to annotate them with `@Context`. In any case the error is not OK. I have opened [#1541](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1541) in the MapStruct issue tracker

Comment: Jennis, We want to use the generic option so we can pass none or many Strings. Example:
createErrorData("code");//zero argument   
createErrorData("code", "hello");//one argument   
createErrorData("code", "my", "name", "is", "varargs");//four arguments

Filip, Using the @Context annotation giving the same exception.

Comment: Filip, Using the @Context annotation giving the same exception.

Comment: you need to prefix the username with @ if you want this person to be notified of your comment

Comment: regarding your response: in the target object varargs are going to be n mapped to an array, aren't they? please post the code of `MyResponse` class and preferably write an example which would show what is the desired results. please don't post it in comments, edit the answer instead